# How do i connect docker pipeline on jenkins to kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, cicd

I am trying to setup a pipeline on jenkins that uses docker containers to execute tasks like for example deploy an helm charts using a docker image with helm

here is what my **Jenkinsfile** looks like

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Helm') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'dtzar/helm-kubectl' }
            }
            steps {
                sh '''
                helm version
                kubectl version
                helm ls
                kubectl get all -n test
                '''

            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it fails at the `helm ls` line because it can not connect to the kubernetes cluster.
How do i connect this pipeline to use the **Kubernetes configuration(kubeconfig)** i have setup

here is error am getting

```
+ helm ls
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable
```

I could not find any documentation on how to connect docker pipeline to connect to the kubernetes cluster
What do i add to the Jenkinsfile to be able to connect?

> **UPDATE**

i also tried this

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Helm') {
            agent {
                docker { image 'dtzar/helm-kubectl' }
            }
            steps {
              withCredentials([kubeconfigContent(credentialsId: 'k8s-cluster', variable: 'KUBECONFIG_CONTENT')]) {
                sh '''
                helm version
                helm ls
                kubectl get all -n test
                '''
              }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and got this error

```
+ helm ls
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable
```

I could not find any documentation on how to connect docker pipeline to connect to the kubernetes cluster

What do i add to the Jenkinsfile to be able to connect?

so seems the docker container is unable to resolve the dns of the kubernetes cluster

how do i resolve this?

Comment: Where do you have the kubeconfig?

Comment: as credentials in jenkins..i am able to use it with *kubernetesDeploy* with reference of the crdentials as `kubeconfigId` here is link to the plugin https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Continuous+Deploy+Plugin

Comment: issue now is how do i reference that in docker pipeline in jenkinsfile so when i run something like helm or kubectl it is able to use that kubeconfig credential to connect to the kubernetes cluster

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is strange solution, but I would like to provide it to you:

You can get actual kubeconfig file from your Kubernetes cluster or locally and change it to base64 format like in example below:

```
- cat /root/.kube/config | base 64
```

Then use your base64 configuration file in pipeline:

```
- echo $your_variable | base64 -d | tee /root/.kube/config
```

In such case you will be having actual kubeconfig file on runner machine.

In case of DNS problem - just need to specify IP address of your runner machine in /etc/resolv.conf file.